# Import Android-Gradle project into Android Studio

Tags: android, import

I'm trying to import a project that I created in another machine using Android Studio, to a new machine, using the same software.

I select "Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)", then select the folder, that have the following structure:

```
  app
  build.gradle
  build
  gradle
  gradle.properties
  gradlew
  gradlew.bat
  local.properties
  settings.gradle
```

The problem is that I cant setup the project like in the other machine, were i created it. In the "Project > Android" appears "Nothing to show".

Comment: Have you tried just "Open" it? Normally if you create a project in AS you don't need to "import" it (e.g., unlike Eclipse project).

Comment: @Android777, I want to commit the code to Github, but I don't want to include *.iml and .idea files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of selecting "Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)," select "Open an existing Android Studio project" then navigate to the topmost build.gradle file of your project.

Comment: I don't know why, but it show always /gradle. I removed that, and a new option appear "using existence gradle (recommended)". 

Now works fine :)

Comment: selecting that option will use a preinstalled gradle on your current machine, which is probably the same version of gradle you used on your first machine. Otherwise, android studio will download a gradle wrapper for you (the one in /gradle directory).

Comment: Maybe was the sleep last night, but now with everything removed except some gradle configurations (and not folders), everything can be imported just fine using open existence project :)

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day